# SFMC: Can the HTML exceeded notification be omitted when previewing and testing emails?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, system-permissions, preview

Being a part of a team of marketeers sending campaign mails daily to +10 markets, we're constantly bothered by the polite SFMC warning telling us our HTML exceeds the limit of some mail client when previewing and testing.

Though this warning is handy, we're very aware of it, and we've also investigated and found that this 'only' means the last part of our mail is clipped. Our deliverability is very good and not affected.

The warning always appears directly on top of our subject, meaning that we need to dismiss it every time when previewing mails before sending.

To add to this: Yes, we're looking into re-arranging the HTML of our footer as one way of fixing this.

But, nevertheless, we'd also like to know: **Is there any way or setting in SFMC that allows us to dismiss this warning temporarily or permanently?**

It'd be really useful, thank you.

[image: HTML exceed warning]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this is built into the back end of SFMC and is not available to be turned off/on by users. You could talk to your Account Executive about it, but I get the feeling that it is not something that is available as an option.